# Function re call on hover

Tags: jquery, html, dictionary

Created custom google map.

**my achievement** -  I need to map 'center' rearrange after div width and height reset on div hover.

**Problem** : When I hover and hold on the div - map center re arrange again and again .
How to solve this issue

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fCRB6/1/) 
 I tired this way

Code

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(21.14580, 79.08815)
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapbox'),
        mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: map.getCenter(),
        icon: 'http://toobler.com/staging/design/hapzis/img/icon-map.png',
        map: map
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
 // hover function
$('#mapbox').hover(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        initialize()
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [off() method](http://api.jquery.com/off/):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fCRB6/3/)

```
$('#mapbox').hover(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        initialize()
    }, 1000);
    $(this).off('hover');                 
});
```

---

Or just set false to initialize function:

```
$('#mapbox').hover(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        initialize();
        initialize = false;
    });
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fCRB6/4/)

Comment: Yes helped your answer , May i ask , how to get normal map center again after mouse leave

Answer (score 1):

You do need off hover

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3XVx/1/)

```
 $('#mapbox').hover(function() {
     setTimeout(function() {
         initialize()
     }, 1000);
     $(this).off('hover');                
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

By default hover function uses mouseout mouseover method so this may not give expected result.

As you only need to initialize your map after mouseleave

Try replacing your hover code with below hope this would help..

```
$('#mapbox').mouseleave(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        initialize()
    },1000);
});
```

see mouseout vs mouseleave [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/different-between-mouseout-and-mouseleave-in-jquery/)